# wget conditional link rewriting

Tags: url-rewriting, hyperlink, wget

I have the following wget command:

```
wget --http-user='user' --http-password='password' --trust-server-names --quiet -r -p -k -E -e robots=off -P /Users/Sebastian/Desktop/test/ http://somedomain.com
```

This does everything I want it to do except the following. It rewrites my canonical link from this:

```
<link rel="canonical" href="http://somedomain.com/somedir/somedir/somedir/folder/" />
```

to this:

```
<link rel="canonical" href="index.html" />
```

Any idea how I can leave canonical links out of the rewrite process?

Comment: I ended up leaving the -k option out of wget, so it doen't touch links at all. After getting the files I iterate over them with `find` and `sed` to rewrite everyting the way I want it to. Not too elegant, but it works.

Answer (score 0):

Can we detect if the URL is tagged as a cannonical just from that given URL?
Because one solution would be just not downloading those pages.

Another solution - just downloading everything. Than removing those Cannonical marked files and rewriting as described [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/287749/can-wget-convert-links-within-a-local-html-document).

Comment: Unfortunately I can't detect that …